# How to create models in django for index and data that already exists in elasticsearch. And also paginate the data fetched

Tags: django, elasticsearch-dsl

My data is stored in elasticsearch database.I want to fetch this data using django ,paginate and display in the front end

I have tried search function of elasticsearch dsl and django paginator.But on click of next page querying the whole set again makes it inefficient.Hence want to convert similar to django queryset.
There will be no write operation to Elastic search